# Can't type angle bracket characters in AmigaOS 4.1 on WinUAE

Tags: amiga, emulation

Has anyone else experienced that when running AmigaOS 4.1 inside WinUAE that they can't type the `<` or `>` characters? I have a mostly bog-standard American QWERTY keyboard, no special emulation settings for the keyboard, and have "American" set as the keyboard type in the OS. The unshifted `,` and `.` work just fine for these keys, it's only when shifting for the angle brackets that results in nothing being typed at all.

Versions:

- Amiga Forever 7 Plus Edition 7.2.*
- RetroPlatform Library 7.1.0.*
- WinUAE 3.6.* - 4.1.* (both 32- and 64-bit builds)

The characters can be properly typed with WinUAE directly, but I cannot recreate my configuration from Amiga Forever (I tried but I keep getting something wrong and I don't know what). So I need a solution that works with AF as opposed to WinUAE itself.

Comment: I tried it (with German keyboard and layout) and experience the same problem, just it is not `<` and `>` but `;` and `:` but I think this is because of our different keyboard layouts. Try to open the programm KeyShow. You find it in your AmigaOS41 partition in “utilities”. Here the keys are shown correctly and you can use that virtual keyboard to type what you want, although that is not very convenient, of course, and no real solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send the keyboard data, Amiga Forever uses the keyboard layout set in the title (right-click, Edit, select the Input tab). Under "Classic" systems like 3.x, this is also autodetected at runtime, but on 4.x it must be set correctly in the title settings. This probably explains why it did not work with the German layout. Set the keyboard to German in the title settings, and it should work.

The answer to why it did not work in the US layout is that Amiga Forever up to 8.0.5.0 sends "<" and ">" as if they were typed with the extra key to the left of the space bar on an international Amiga layout. This is mapped correctly on Amiga OS up to 3.x (also for the USA 0/1/2 keymaps), but seems to be missing in AmigaOS 4, thus the key produces no output. As of Amiga Forever 8.0.6.0, "<" and ">" are now sent using the non-international Amiga keyboard variant, and so should work also with keymaps where the international variants are missing.

Comment: Yeah I noticed after buying AF8 that the angle brackets started working properly in AmigaOS 4. Honestly, that alone made the upgrade worth it.